# My dialog box is closing my keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialog

I've been at this problem for a while now and I cannot fix it...

I have a very simple activity, the layout has an `EditText` and a `Button`.

The `Button` launches a `Dialog`.

The problem is when the `EditText` is focused. The soft keyboard will be visible, and if the `Button` is pressed at this time, the keyboard closes and the `Dialog` opens. I would like the state of the keyboard to be maintained (closed/open) whenever the `Dialog` is created.

I'm not adding any code to this question, as it's a very standard dialog.

**ALSO**, I cannot use an `AlertDialog` (which would solve the problem), due to needing full customization of the dialog. With an `AlertDialog`, It's impossible to get rid of the rounded border.

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Does your dialog contain any `EditText`s? If yes, then add a <request focus /> tag inside it in the layout file or call requestFocus() on it.

Comment: Nope, I just want the dialog to hover over anything that's already open. (i.e. the soft-input open on the activity).

Comment: I'm not sure if anything can come on top of keyboard.

Comment: @Szymon Not true, an `AlertDialog` does not interrupt the current state of a soft-keyboard. I would like the regular `Dialog` to do the same.

Comment: Ok, I thought you wanted it to be on top of keyboard (hiding keyboard).

Comment: Currently, if the keyboard is open when I launch the Dialog, it closes the keyboard before it shows the dialog. I would like the keyboard to stay open if it's open. @Szymon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, after a few months ;)

Basically. I got rid of the dialog entirely, and added a `visiblity="gone"` LinearLayout inside of a `FrameLayout` (in the layout of the activity).

Whenever I wanted the dialog to pop up, I would set the visibility of the dialog to `visibility="visible"`.